# Adding properties to Koa2's context in Typescript

Tags: typescript, koa2

I want to use Facebook's DataLoader with Koa2 in Typescript.  I want per-request DataLoader instances to go with my per-request database connections.  How is this best achieved?

My current approach is to augment the Koa2 context but I'm failing because I don't know how to fix the type definition.

Here is my attempt at module augmentation...

```
import 'koa';

declare module 'koa' {
    namespace Application {
        interface BaseContext {
            dataLoader(): any;
        }
    }
}

Application.BaseContext.prototype.dataLoader = function() {
    console.log("Cannot find name 'Application' at line 11 col 1");
}
```

In addition to the error shown in the log call, I also get `Property 'dataLoader' does not exist on type 'BaseContext'` when I import the above and attempt to call `dataLoader`.

Cheers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just figured out an approach that doesn't require any type-hacking:

```js
interface ICustomAppContext {
  mySlowToInitializeClient: string;
}

interface ICustomAppState {
  poop: string;
}

const app = new Koa<ICustomAppState, ICustomAppContext>();
```

See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b081a5b7d0db7181901d7834f8a85206af263094/types/koa/index.d.ts#L434 for details.

Comment: That's the right answer, you don't need to use module augmentation is the type is already flexible

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to extend the defaults: 

```
interface CustomAppContext extends DefaultContext {
  meta: string;
}

const app = new Koa<DefaultState, CustomAppContext>();
```

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to understand more how this works.

You can indeed do something like:

```
import { Context } from "koa";

declare module "koa" {
    /**
     * See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html for
     * more on declaration merging
     */
    interface Context {
        myProperty: string;
        myOtherProperty: number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

OK, well I guess I still have a lot to learn.  The solution to the typing problem seems to be...

```
import { BaseContext } from 'koa';

declare module 'koa' {
  interface BaseContext {
    dataLoader(): any;
  }
}
```

And, because `BaseContext` is an interface and not a class, you have to define the `dataLoader` implementation after you have instantiated Koa's `Application` class.

```
const app = new Application();

app.context.dataLoader = function() {
  console.log('OK, this works.');
}
```

`app.context` *is* the prototype used to create each request's context object.

I'd appreciate any comments regarding the correctness of this answer.  Thanks.

Ah... learning in public.

Comment: ```import { BaseContext } from 'koa';``` is not necessary